# Android In-App Billing handling resources

Tags: android

I am reading the developer docs about how to implement In-App billing and I'm still wrapping my head around it. This is probably a stupid question but, do the resources for the purchasable content already have to exist in the apk? in which case a successful transaction simply unlocks these items in the app, or can new/additional resources be imported to the app after the purchase is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either option is possible for your app.  Just keep in mind that the in-app billing support from Google doesn't give you an automatic way to download new resources, instead you would have to self-host the new resources and have the app manually download them.  If you don't have the capacity for that, then your best bet is to just keep the resources inside your apk.